# Handle multiple API requests parallel from angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, http-post

I need to call multiple API request from my angular app parallel and i need to get each response separately(need to do some different actions for each response) and also i need to track when all the request finished the execution

for example i have an array of request arr1[request1,request2,request3,request4]  and each request will take different time to get the response.so i need to do different actions like actn1,actn2,actn3..etc according to the response.i need to call each action in FCFS manner. some request will finish execution faster than other request so whenever i get response of each request i need to call corresponding action and finally after getting all response i need to call finalAction also.

By using forkJoin am able to execute my  finalAction(after finished all request execution this has to work) but i don't know how i will execute each response action whenever the response came from the server

Comment: Try using `combineLatest()` which ensures every observable emits at least 1 value: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Comment: As i am new to angular can u give a basic code for the above example with this combineLatest()

Comment: I already posted as an answer with using `tap` pipeable operator.

Comment: ok thanks,let me try this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `combineLatest()` which ensures every observable emits at least 1 value.
And you can use `.pipe()` and `tap()` for any of the observables to take individual action.

```
combineLatest([

   req1.pipe(tap(result => {
     /* take action */
   })),

   req2.pipe(tap(result => {
     /* take another action */
   })),

   req3.pipe(tap(result => {
     /* take a super action */
   })),

   req4.pipe(tap(result => {
     /* do nothing maybe */
   }))

]).subscribe((resultArray) => {
  /* take the final action as all of the observables emitted at least 1 value */
})
```

`combineLatest` reference: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

`tap` reference: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do

---

**UPDATE**

If you have a dynamic length of array, you can use `Array.map()` inside `combineLatest()` to iterate over observables

```
const requests = [req1,req2,req3,..., reqN]

combineLatest(
  requests.map(req => req.pipe(tap(res => handleResponse(res))))
).subscribe();

const handleResponse = (response) => { /*do something*/ }
```

Here's a working stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-a16kbu

Comment: thanks for the answer and it is working for 4 request but i need this as dynamic.For example, that request array is a dynamic array,the number of request will be vary so i tried by adding all the request in an array and tried loop inside CombineLatest but it is showing syntax issue,can i write some loop inside CombineLatest????

Comment: Updated the answer to cover your need and added a stackblitz project link.

Comment: let me try this,Thanks for the help

Comment: this is working perfectly,Thanks again,,, i did a small change in the code and i am just adding that down

Comment: Thanks, working perfect on Angular8. Also, thanks for the update, that's the version I'm using.

Comment: Perfect example for me as I have multiple type of `Observables` to listen at individual as well as combined level

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from @Harun Yilmaz post,Just i am adding that here for others reference.

```
getDataFromApi(url) {
    let httpOptions={};
    let param=["CAL3","CAL2","CAL1"];//dynamic parameter(CAL1:8sec,CAL2:5s,CAL3:12s)
    let httpArray=[];
for(let i=0;i<param.length;i++){
      httpArray.push(this.http.post<any>(url + `/PostDataSet?Id=${param[i]}`, {}, httpOptions))
   }
   const handleResponse = (response) => {
       //here i am getting each response in a first come first manner
       console.log(response.Table[0].Output);
      }
const combineResponse =combineLatest(
  httpArray.map(req => req.pipe(tap(handleResponse)))
   )
    return combineResponse;
}
//output
 CAL2
 CAL1
 CAL3
```

Comment: You can simplify array creation like: `let httpArray = param.map(p => this.http.post<any>( \`${url}/PostDataSet?Id=${p}\`, {}, httpOptions))`